# define an array in function in C

Tags: c, function, data-structures

```
#include     <stdio.h> 
#include    <conio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#define  MAX 5

int insert(int,int,int);
int del(int,int,int);
int display(int,int,int);

void main()    
{    
    int queue[MAX],    front ,    rear;    
    int n;    
    front= -1;    
    rear=  -1;    
    clrscr();    
    while(1)    
    {    
    printf   ("\n Operation on list ");    
    printf   ("\n1: Insert\n 2: Delete\n 3: Display\n 4: Reset\n 5: Exit");    
    printf   ("\nEnter your choise(1/2/3/4/5):");    
    scanf   ("%d",&n);        
    switch (n)    
    {    
        case 1:{    
            insert(queue[MAX], front,rear);    
            break;    
            }    
        case 2:{     
            del(queue[MAX],front,rear);     
            break;     
            }     
        case 3:{      
            display(queue[MAX],front,rear);       
            break;       
            }       
        case 4:{       
            front=-1;       
            rear=-1;       
            break;       
            }       
        case 5:{       
            exit(1);       
                    }       
            }       
        }       
}       
int insert(int queue[MAX],int front,int rear)        
{       
    int i;     
    printf("\n Enter the data");      
    scanf("%d",&i);      
    if(rear==MAX-1)       
    {      
        printf("\nOVERFLOW");       
        return (0);        
    }        
    else if(front==-1)       
    {        
        (front)++;        
        (rear)++;         
        queue[rear]=i;        
            }          
    (rear)++;        
    queue[rear]=i;        
}        
int del(int queue[MAX],int front,int rear)          
{          
    int i;        
    if(front==-1 && rear==-1)         
    {         
        printf("\nUNDERFLOW");          
        return (0);          
    }         
    else if(front==(rear+1))        
    {         
        printf("\nUNDERFLOW");           
        return (0);         
    }         
           else       
    {       
            i=queue[front];       
    (front)++;       
    printf("\nThe element deleted is %d ",i);        
    }       
}         
int display(int queue[MAX], int front, int rear)      
{      
    int i;       
        if(front==-1 && rear==-1)        
    {       
        printf("\nEmptu queue");       
        return (0);       
    }        
    else if(front==(rear+1))      
    {        
        printf("\nNo elements in queue");       
        return (0);      
    }       
    else       
    {       
    printf("\n The elements in queue are :");        
    for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)        
    printf("%d\n",queue[i]);       
    }       
}
```

No compilation error.But i am having 3 run time error
1. undefined symbol `insert  (int,int,int)`
2. undefined symbol `display  (int,int,int)`
3. undefined symbol `del (int,int,int)`
i think it is due to the deceleration of array. how can i define array in function initialization

Comment: There is no way that you're getting "undefined symbol" as a *run-time* error.

Comment: i am getting.. you can run the code and see by it yoursel

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your functions with the same signature as their definitions.  For example:

```
int display(int,int,int);
```

Should be:

```
int display(int queue[MAX], int front, int rear);
```

Comment: There is no need to specify the names of variables, `int display(int[MAX],int,int);` should work.

Comment: More precisely, the compiler complains about the first argument not being an int but an array of int.

Comment: @AlterMann sir its not working.. error like cannot convert int int * is showing. i am just simply trying to run the program using array not pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You must get a compilation error, since the declaration and definition of **insert,del,display**
Conflicts.

> Modify code this way
>
> Prototype:

```
int insert(int *queue,int front,int rear);
int del(int *queue,int front,int rear);
int display(int *queue,int front,int rear);
```

> Declaration

```
int insert(int queue[],int front,int rear) {

     ****** insert Operation *******

}
```

Same with other operations

> Delete and Display , When you call these functions from main call them like this

```
insert(queue,front,rear);
```

Answer (score 0):

**2 changes**

You should pass `queue` from `main()` instead of `queue[MAX]`

```
insert(queue,front,rear);
del(queue,front,rear);
display(queue,front,rear);
```

And in the declarations of functions do this:

```
int insert(int[],int,int);
int del(int[],int,int);
int display(int[],int,int);
```

**A bigger problem**

There is one more problem with the code the variables `front` and `rear` are passed by value in the `insert()` function.

Now do this to correct it.

Declaration:  `int insert(int[],int*,int*);`

From `main()` : `insert(queue,&front,&rear);`

In definition do this:

```
int insert(int queue[MAX],int *front,int *rear)
{
int i;
printf("\n Enter the data");
scanf("%d",&i);
if(*rear==MAX-1)
{
    printf("\nOVERFLOW");
    return (0);
}
else if(*front==-1)
{
    (*front)++;
    (*rear)++;
    queue[*rear]=i;
        }
(*rear)++;
queue[*rear]=i;
}
```

Do the same thing for `del()`. It is not necessary to do it for `display()`.
You program should work fine now.

Comment: its working i am not getting any run tinme error but my data are not storing queue.. every time i insert data in queue and running the display function its showing empty queue.

Comment: Ok I got your problem, let me update my post. You should pass pointers to front and rear in your insert function

Comment: You can check the corrected code now whether it is working or not. And remember to accept the answer if you liked it. :)

Comment: the modified is using pointer. it is correct.as i have already implemented using pointer. But i am trying to implement using only array  not pointer

Comment: But if you want to change the values of `front` and `rear` you have to pass them by `reference`. Otherwise, if you pass them by value, the `front` and `rear` will always be -1.
There is an `alternative` to this but I would not suggest to use this,you can increase front and rear in `main()` and then pass them in the function according to your convenience. But it is `highly` unsuggested.

Answer (score 0):

Passing array is not like your way.

So function call should be

```
insert(queue, front,rear); //same for others
```

instead

```
insert(queue[MAX], front,rear);.
```

Also declaration should be

```
int insert (int queue[],int,int ); //same for others
```

You have to know about how to [pass array as function argument.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm)

You are passing `front` and `rear` variables as copy of it(passed by value). need pass the address of them.

like

```
insert(queue, &front,&rear); //same for others
```

and at receive side your function should be

```
 int insert (int queue[MAX],int *front,int *rear ) //same for others
 {
   .......
 }
```

**Edit**

you can see edited code here http://pastebin.com/pxX8ZqAj

Comment: using this code. the code is running but data which are being inserted are not stored in queue. while running display function the queue is showing empty

Comment: @user2829263 Probably down voting to answer in two situation first one obviously wrong answer and second one is lack of knowledge to understand the answer.